Task occasionally fails silently in ASP.NET MVC controller
With an ASP.NET MVC controller, I call a function runPreflighter that runs a task. This task loops on a set of given files, runs them through an external rest API, reads a log file, and updates a database with the the results.
Occasionally, the task fails silently, and calls update the database with the error/emails to send to users with the error do not complete.
Running the same files later on completes the task successfully.
I am struggling to find out why the task fails without notice. Is there a way to attach to a task after it ran to see what it's doing? Even when the API is deployed?
public static int runPreflighter(List<string> torun, int techID, string forcedEnv, preFlighterRunData runData, string sendEmail, string email)
{
    int runid = PTADB.startAsyncJob(techid, PTADB.getPreflighterId(forcedEnv), forcedEnv);
Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in torun)
        {
            string preflightlog = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), "Preflight_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".log");
            string preflightCmdLine = string.Format("-s {0} -p {1} \"{2}\" ", runData.inspireServer, runData.inspirePort, runData.wfdFile);
            preflightCmdLine += string.Format(" -warningconfig \"vcs:\\\\Job Settings\\WarningConfigs\\9078.wpr\" -e NULL -useincluded \"*\"  -l \"{0}\" ", preflightlog);
            PTADB.updateRunDetails(runid, "", "", "", "Preflighting for " + file, forcedEnv);

            try
            {
                ToolRunStatus status = new ToolRunStatus { toolrunid = runid, job = "", sub = "", cycle = "", status = "Preflighting for " + file };
                Ignite.runCommandLineAsBatch(runData.inspireServerFile, preflightCmdLine, file, "", "", "", "", "", forcedEnv, runData.hamburg, false, status);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            // mysteriously & randomly fails here, i.e. file 6 of 9
        }

        PTADB.endAsyncJob(runid, 'Y', "", forcedEnv);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Update Database with error result, send email to user
        PTADB.endAsyncJob(runid, 'N', ex.Message, forcedEnv);

        // Send email to user that this failed
        List<string> to = new List<string> { email };
        string message = string.Format("Preflight failed for WFD {0} - {1}", runData.wfdFile, ex.Message);
        string subject = string.Format("Failed: Preflighter Encountered an error for {0}", runData.wfdFile);
        Email.sendEmail(subject, message, to);
      }
    });
    return runid;
}


So you are doing fire-and-forget on ASP.NET, correct?

Please don't fire tasks in a Web API context like this. Instead, create a dedicated hosted service background worker that gets work pushed to it, or just leverage some well-known library that does this like Hangfire, Quartz, or even go with something like Azure Functions/AWS Lambdas triggered via EventGrid/EventBridge. What you are doing is flat out dangerous and won't scale well. This is of course just a suggestion/recommendation and not a direct response (thus why I'm adding it as a comment).

Correct, fire and forget @TheodorZoulias

Well, if you search for "c# fire and forget asp net" in your favorite search engine, you'll find plenty of stuff to read. This is an overly discussed topic. The experts advise against doing it for decades, and their arguments are pretty solid.
